# Checking for no duplicate values in an array

Tags: solidity

I have an `uint256[]` array. I need to check that no value is repeated in the array more than once.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Oh, it seems I just should use two enclosed loops.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on whether you will need to remove a number from the array. Let us assume no, because it wasn't mentioned.

You have an array of values. In addition, a mapping of values to bools, which you require are false on before appending a new value, and set to true as you go.

`mapping(uint => bool) public exists;`

Hope it helps.

p.s. This an other common patterns are described over here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)